# IONIC 3 - sqlite3_step failure: cannot rollback - no transaction is active

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic-framework, ionic3

tengo este error desde hace algunos días, si alguien sabe a que se debe le agradecería muchísimo la ayuda.

Esto al parecer el al momento de cargar el storage.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

// IMPORT URL SERVICES
import { URL_SERVICES } from '../../config/url.services';

import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular'
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/index.pages';

//pluguin storage
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class UsersProvider {

  token:string;
  id_user:string;

  constructor(public http: Http,
              private alertCtrl:AlertController,
              private platform:Platform,
              private storage:Storage,
              private modalCtrl:ModalController) {

              //aqui cargamos el storage, (falta el loading)
              this.load_storage();
            }

  //para validar si inicio session algun usuario y mostrar por ej el boton de salir
  activo():boolean{
    if( this.token ){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }

  ingresar( email:string, password:string ){

    //PARA ENVIAR LOS DATOS
    let data = new URLSearchParams();

    //append para cade header a enviar
    data.append("email", email);
    data.append("password", password);

    //URL A LA CUAL HAREMOS EL POST
    let url = URL_SERVICES + '/login';

    //respuesta asincrona para poner un load
    //creamos un observador
    return this.http.post(url, data)
    .map( res=>{ //esta respuesta viene con codigo del error y los headers
      let data_res = res.json();
      console.log(data_res);

      //validamos si viene algun error
      if( data_res.err ){
        //creamos una alerta
        this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: "Error al Iniciar",
          subTitle: data_res.message,
          buttons: ["OK"]
        }).present();

      }else{
        //no vienen errores
        this.token = data_res.token;
        this.id_user = data_res.id_user;

        //GUARDAR STORAGE
        this.save_storage();

      }

    })//aqui deberia suscribirme porque es un observador, pero lo hare en otro lado
  }

  cerrar_session(){
    this.token = null;
    this.id_user = null;

    //guardar storage
    this.save_storage();

    this.modalCtrl.create(LoginPage)
    .present();
  }

  public save_storage(){

    console.log('entre a SAVE storage');

    if( this.platform.is("cordova") ){
      //dispositivo
      console.log('entre a SAVE storage DISPOSITIVO');
      this.storage.set('token', this.token);
      this.storage.set('id_user', this.id_user);
    }else{
      //computadora
      console.log('entre a SAVE storage COMPUTADORA');
      if( this.token ){
        localStorage.setItem("token", this.token);
        localStorage.setItem("id_user", this.id_user);
      }else{
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        localStorage.removeItem("id_user");
      }
    }
  }

  public load_storage(){
    //esta es una promesa
    console.log('entre a CARGAR storage');
    let promesa = new Promise( ( resolve, reject )=>{

      if( this.platform.is("cordova") ){
        //dispositivo
        console.log('entre a CARGAR storage DISPOSITIVO');
        this.storage.ready().then( ()=>{

          this.storage.get("token").then( (token)=>{
            console.log('load storage', token);//prueba
            if( token ){
              this.token = token;
            }
          })

          this.storage.get("id_user").then( (id_user)=>{
            console.log('load storage', id_user);//prueba
            if( id_user ){
              this.id_user = id_user;
            }
            resolve();
          })

        })
      }else{
        //computadora
        console.log('entre a CARGAR storage PC');
        if( localStorage.getItem("token") ){

          this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
          this.id_user = localStorage.getItem("id_user");
        }
        resolve();
      }

    });

    return promesa;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo no sabría responderte, porque haría falta ver más código.

Pero te puedo decir en qué consiste ese error.

Se está intentando ejecutar una transacción. Una transacción es un conjunto de modificaciones en la base de datos que deben realizarse TODAS o NINGUNA. Es decir, que si una modificación falla, para que la base de datos no se quede a mitad (lo cual podría producir problemas de inconsistencia, o que se queden registros a mitad), si la transacción no se completa la base de datos vuelve al punto original (rollback).

Cuando se termina de realizar una transacción, se debe ejecutar un COMMIT para que todos los cambios hechos hasta el momento queden grabados para siempre. Si algo ha fallado, se debe ejecutar un ROLLBACK que deshace todos los cambios realizados hasta el momento del error.

Pero estos dos comandos fallan (ocurre una excepción) si no se ha iniciado una transacción. En tu error, se está pretendiendo hacer un rollback cuando en realidad, no se ha iniciado una transacción.

Para que se inicie una transacción se debe ejecutar el comando sql "BEGIN TRANSACTION", o usando los métodos de la clase SQLiteDataBase, sería un db.beginTransaction().

Por tanto, yo comenzaría a buscar en qué punto de tu código estás llamando a rollback, o en qué punto del código deberías inicializar una transacción. Quizás sea algún método interno de ionic que debas tener en cuenta que trabaja con transacciones.